# Reading all excel files from a directory instead of listing them individually

Tags: python, pandas

I made a program to merge excel files based on listing their specific file names [4] but if I want merge all files listed in a particular directory (say a folder called test on my desktop) how would I go about this?

```
 import pandas as pd
 import os 
 os.chdir("/users/me/desktop/test") 
 excel_names = ["/users/me/desktop/test/test1.xlsx", "/users/me/desktop/test/test2.xlsx"]
 excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

 frames = [pd.read_excel(x, header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]
 frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

 combined = pd.concat(frames)

 combined.to_excel("combine.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: First, are you sure you need to do this? If you just run your script with `myscript /path/to/sheets/*.xls`, the shell will turn that glob pattern into a list of all of the matching files, and your code won’t know or care whether its arguments came from you listing specific names or you using a glob pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this, depending on your specific criteria:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(i, header=None, index_col=None) for i in os.listdir() if i.endswith('.xlsx')])
```